# Difference between 2 dates in seconds

Tags: php, date

In my project, I need to calculate the **difference in seconds between two dates**:

For example:

```
$firstDay = "2011-05-12 18:20:20";
$secondDay = "2011-05-13 18:20:20";
```

Then I should get **86400 Seconds** That is 24 hours.

Similarly for

```
$firstDay = "2011-05-13 11:59:20";
$secondDay = "2011-05-13 12:00:20";
```

It should return **60 Seconds**.

I read lots of questions on Stack Overflow but they only deal with the difference between **2 minute fields** like **11:50:01 and 12:10:57**

Answer (score 180, accepted):

```
$timeFirst  = strtotime('2011-05-12 18:20:20');
$timeSecond = strtotime('2011-05-13 18:20:20');
$differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
```

You will then be able to use the seconds to find minutes, hours, days, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I used this on a form that was getting spammed. I compare the time stamps in seconds (hidden field with form timestamp and then php when the form is submitted), if it's too fast like 5 seconds then don't submit the form.