# Time since in php dateTime object in seconds

Tags: php, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date to timestamp (PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113829/date-to-timestamp-php)

How do I get the current time in seconds since 1st january 1970 in php?

does the dateTime object support anything since as

```
$date1 = new DateTime("01/01/1970");   
$return = since($date1, date.now());
```

The problem I get here is I could just do something like ((minutes=hours *60)*60)

Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `time()` call?

Comment: `$dateTime = new DateTime; echo $dateTime->format('U');`

Comment: @Gordon The reason I didn't think this was a duplicate is because I want to know if my since() function is correct

Comment: your `since` function is superfluous. Either use `strtotime` or use the DateTime API. Also see [Difference between 2 dates in seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988450/difference-between-2-dates-in-seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `time()` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: ah, but this link doesn't appear to have anything with regards to a since() function, I only guessed at that method above as I couldn't find anything on it on first look

Answer (score 0):

`time()`
Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Comment: ah awesome, would my since() function work like the one above?

Comment: you dont need a since function, time(); CONTAINS the number of seconds since 1970, just echo it.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];` is a pretty light way to do it, if your server supports it. Otherwise you have the usual time() / strtotime() functions. Also, why is there javascript in your PHP?