# Unexpected (negative time) when calculating the elpased time between two dates - php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to get difference in seconds between the current date and certain date which is stored in a database as `DATETIME` type. I'm getting this date with this function:

```
function get_date_last_action($username)
{
    $id = $this->get_username_id($username);
    $query = "SELECT date_last_action".
             "FROM user".
             "WHERE user.id ='" . $id . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $date_last_action = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $date_last_action[0];
}
```

In a another code, I call this function:

```
$date = $h_db_functions->get_date_last_action("user1"); 
$currentTime = time();
$timeInPast = strtotime($date);
$differenceInSeconds = $currentTime - $timeInPast;
```

What's weird is that I'm getting a **negative value**.

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($date);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting a negative answer to "now - then", then "then" is in the future.

To confirm, try `echo $date`.

If the difference is fairly small, then it means your database and PHP processes are not using the same timezone. Be sure to set `date_default_timezone_set` in PHP, and `SET time_zone = ...` in MySQL, to the same identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach:

```
$timeFirst  = strtotime('2014-04-15 18:20:20');
$timeSecond = strtotime('2014-04-11 18:20:20');
$differenceInSeconds = $timeSecond - $timeFirst;
```

Note: Be sure, that you are executing the functions with right parameters.

In your case:

```
$currentTime = time();
$timeInPast = strtotime($date); // date should be in YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS format
$result = $currentTime - $timeInPast;
```

Sources:

1. [`date()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
2. [`strtotime()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
3. [method source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5988503/2898694)

[Demo](http://ideone.com/0b1Ov2)

Comment: date returns a string.

Comment: strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) = time() = OP already wrote this.

Comment: @Dexa :) thank you. updated again. forget about this :)