# How to check if the difference between 2 dates is bigger than 15 minutes?

Tags: php, datetime

I am using this function to compare a date from the database to the current date, and i need to check if the difference between the 2 dates is bigger than 15 minutes but i don't know how to do that, i think i need to do something like `if($comp > 0 days 0 hours 15 minutes)`

```
function TimeOut($dateP){
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$date2 =  new DateTime($dateP);

   echo $comp = $date->diff($date2)->format("%d days %h hours and %i minuts %s seconds");
    if ($comp > "15 minutes ?") {
    return true;
 }
}
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/5988450/1244597

Comment: Don't check against the diff format. Get the actual diff and check against that.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113940/compare-given-date-with-today

Comment: Convert both to a Unix timestamp and check if the difference is greater than `(15*60)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use diff and then read the m parameter of the result. In the example below $difference will be [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object:

```
$difference = $start_date->diff($date2);

if($difference->i > 15) {
    echo "difference greater than 15 minutes"
}
```

> A date interval stores either a fixed amount of time (in years,
>   months, days, hours etc) or a relative time string in the format that
>   DateTime's constructor supports.

Comment: That works, but didn't you meant `$difference->i`  since `->m` is for months ?