# Calculate time difference in seconds between 2 dates PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have to 2 dates values in PHP,

```
start_date_time = "2018-03-15T20:39:06Z"

end_date_time = "2018-03-17T12:42:08Z"

duration = ?  // in seconds
```

I actually want to get total time in seconds. Please help

Comment: I copy/paste your question in Google, first link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988450/difference-between-2-dates-in-seconds

Comment: Looks more like c#

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date_time  = strtotime('2011-05-12 18:20:20');
$end_date_time = strtotime('2011-05-13 18:20:20');

$durationeInSeconds = $start_date_time - $end_date_time;
```

Comment: You should include a description of why this is a valid solution.